# Solving an ODE involving an unknown function g (x)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, laplace-method

> Solve this ODE using Laplace transforms

$$y'''(x) - 6y''(x) +11y'(x) - 6y (x) = g (x)$$ with $y (0) = 1 $ and $y'(0)  = y''(0) = 0$

This is very strange. How do I solve this if $g (x)$ is unknown? I believe this requires convolution, but I don't know how to proceed after applying the laplace transforms.

Comment: Start by applying the Laplace transform on both sides and use the rule:
$$L(f')=sL(f)+f(0)$$
and the ones for higher derivatives. Then some things should cancel out so that you can take isolate the Laplace transform of $y$ on the left hand side. Then do the Laplace inverse transform on both sides and you should be good.

Comment: @RyanJ How does the accepted answer lead you to a solution? Note the unresolved Laplace transform at the end, and compare with the approach in the other answer, which leads to a fully explicit solution.

Comment: @Did To be honest, neither response really helped me. But I'll accept the other answer

Comment: If the other answer "did not really help you" this means you are lacking some basics of the subject. The (entirely standard) keywords here are: characteristics equation, complementary solution, variation of parameters, general solution. Which ones are not fully understood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
the characteristics equation
$$r^3-6r^2+11r-6=0$$
$$(r-1)(r-2)(r-3)-0$$
so the complementary solution is
$$y_c=c_1e^x+c_2e^{2x}+c_3e^{3x}$$
then use the variation of parameters to find the general solution [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters)